# What does "compound" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tientsin_incident

> In addition, there were divisions within the Japanese government between one faction that wanted to use the crisis to start a war with Britain and another that argued that since the war with China was already **compounded** the border war with the Soviet Union, starting a third war at this time was unwise

I understand the first 1-2 parts of the sentence: there were internal divisions in the Japanese government regarding a new war with Britain due to how the war with China progressed. Also, the part after the last comma is obvious, but the part in between depends on the meaning of "compounded", but no meaning I know of for "compounded" makes sense there.
I would have understood if it had been followed by *with* or something like that. Maybe a comma or a dash to emphasize how to stress it would make the meaning more obvious?

Comment: I think you are right: it looks like there is a word -- or more than one -- missing after "compounded" in the quote

Comment: It's poorly written.

Comment: Perhaps "**was** already compounded" should be "**had** already compounded..." See [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/compound)'s *VERB **2** Make (something bad) worse; intensify the negative aspects of*. Or simply missing the word **by**.

Comment: Or they might have meant to write *compounding*.